# ssh session timeout using openssh client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I have a system which I can reach via ssh. I can reach it from a windows PC using putty and from a ubuntu system (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS).

When I connect with putty to the system and doing the following command: `ldd /my_binary`
everything works fine - it gives a list of about 20 libraries.

When I do the same coming from ubuntu, the output starts with about 10 lines. After that it stops and some minutes later the connections breaks down with: `Timeout, server  not responding`

The ssh option KeepAlive is configured on ssh server and ubuntu ssh client.

Versions:
ubuntu ssh client OpenSSH_6.6.1p1
server (it's a appliance) OpenSSH_4.3p2

I set the LogLever on ssh server on DEBUG2, but it is no upcoming error message.

Do you have any suggestion whats wrong on the ubuntu client?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a defect network card. I removed it and put in a new one and everything works fine now.